# Error with coordinates of skeleton_to_csgraph (python)

Tags: python, coordinates, error-reporting

I am using skeleton-to-csgraph() to analyse the skeleton I have obtained and this function should send me back some data and among them, all the coordinates of all the points of the skeleton in a matrix [(N+1) x 2] with N the number of points. However there is one situation where this function gives me a coordinates matrix with some error for no reasons.
Does someone knows from where the error could come from ?

More information about the function and the package here:
https://jni.github.io/skan/

[Lines of the coordinates matrix given by skeleton-to-csgraph function. At the line 326 an unexplained error, it should be an int and not a float value because it is a pixel index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnwWN.png)

with grid, a ndarray of int32 [200,100] with value of 1 or 0. File in this link:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/12xwZBv3RKQ4Q802jXPAhtYZXHrsMytMl?usp=sharing

```
skeleton, distance = medial_axis(grid, return_distance=True)
graph, coordinates, degrees = skeleton_to_csgraph(skeleton)
```

Like on the picture, I obtained none integer value for one coordinate

Comment: pls add your code and full error trace log. thanks

Comment: my error come from another part of my code, but it is due to the error I describe here, the funtion skeleton_to_csgraph is suppose to send me something that it dont. the error I describe here generate no error and that is the matter

Comment: I am new on this platform and I dont know how to share you the input that makes this error

Comment: when I ran, I was able to get the graph, and finally was able to generate image `draw.overlay_skeleton_networkx(graph,coordinates, image=skeleton,axis=ax)` and in coordinates received value and none of it is zero. is the image, your objective?

Comment: I want the coordinates matrix with only integer values for the next

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you're encountering is because skan needs to collapse junction pixels into their centroid in order to produce a coherent graph. See https://doi.org/10.7717/peerj.4312/supp-2 for details. Apologies that this is not better documented. I've made an issue to improve this in the future:

https://github.com/jni/skan/issues/121

This issue is also related: the coordinates array contains all node coordinates but also some junk coordinates:

https://github.com/jni/skan/issues/108

Feel free to continue the discussion on github!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'll check on github, I didnt check before and I hadn't the reflex to go.

Comment: But if I well understand, it is not normal to obtain this error value ? it should be index instead of float coordinates ?

Comment: No, they are node coordinates, and they can be floating point ("subpixel").

Comment: But sometime I obtain twice a coordinate also ( in my first post/question, it is the nodes 328 ), is that normal too ?

Comment: Also normal, just *less* normal  Basically, for every node ID there is a coordinate... But there is also "left over" coordinates from pixels that were collapsed. Sometimes the collapsed and the "summary" coordinates match. We'll try to fix this in the future by removing the "junk" coordinates. But the rule is: you should only look at the coordinates array from the node IDs. There is no guarantee that all coordinates in that array are "real".

Comment: oooh I understand! Thank you for your confirmation :) I hope it will be not too complicated to fixe this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The following steps followed:
Note: I ran this on jupyter notebook, so you will see! at start of installation

```
!pip install git+https://github.com/jni/skan # install latest version github
```

load the data, and process it.

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.morphology import medial_axis
from skan import skeleton_to_csgraph
from skan import _testdata
from skan import draw
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
grid = np.load('grid.npy') # this is the file you shared through google drive

skeleton, distance = medial_axis(grid, return_distance=True)
graph, coordinates, degrees = skeleton_to_csgraph(skeleton)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
draw.overlay_skeleton_networkx(graph,coordinates, image=skeleton,axis=ax)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
draw.overlay_skeleton_2d(grid, skeleton, dilate=1, axes=ax);
```

[image]

[Complete code screen snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNvEK.png)

Comment: Can you look in you coordinates matrix line 325 ? because it is there I have 2 values that I should not have ( values which are not integer )!
I am able to run and plot this also but the strange thing is that we have not integer values in the coordinates matrix where we should only have integer becausre it refers to the position in the matrix, so if I want to manipulate this data ( coordinates ), I cant due to this error

Comment: these are values(float - [115.33333333  11.33333333]) are based on grid. if you want to override it, you can do `coordinates[325]=[115,11]` and then feed it into the next processing.

Comment: I have a solution to overcome this problem it is that:
a = np.where(skeleton == 1 ) / 
b = np.array([a[0], a[1]]).transpose() /
coordinates = np.vstack(([0,0],b))         /
But we are agree there is a problem with the function! It shouldn't give back float values

Comment: great! as this is lib of skan, pls see if you can log an issue with the authors of lib.

Comment: I'll see. Thank you for your time and your confirmation. :)

Answer (score 0):

It seams there is a problem with the function `skeleton-to-csgraph()` in some specific cases. But to overcome this error, the following code provides the result you should have:

```
a = np.where(skeleton == 1 )
b = np.array([a[0], a[1]]).transpose()
coordinates = np.vstack(([0,0],b))
```

with skeleton, the numpy array with the image of your skeleton and coordinates, the result you should obtain with `skeleton-to-csgraph()` which contains all the coordinates of the skeleton points.